# (VueJS) Update parent data from child component

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I have a parent who's passing props to a child and the child emits events to the parent. However this is not fully working and I am not sure why. Any suggestions?

Parent:

```
<template>
<div class="natural-language">
    <div class="natural-language-content">
        <p class="natural-language-results">
            <msm-select :options="payments" :model="isShowingUpdate" />
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import msmSelect from '../form/dropdown.vue'

export default {
    components: {
        'msm-select': msmSelect
    },
    data() {
        return {
            isShowingUpdate: true,
            payments: [
                {'value': 'paying anuualy', 'text': 'paying anuualy'},
                {'value': 'paying monthly', 'text': 'paying monthly'}
            ],
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Child:

```
<template>
<div class="form-pseudo-select">
    <select :model="flagValue" @change="onChange($event.target.value)">
        <option disabled value='Please select'>Please select</option>
        <option v-for="(option, index) in options" :value="option.value">{{ option.text }}</option>
    </select>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
        options: {
            elType: Array
        },
        isShowingUpdate: {
            type: Boolean
        }
    },
    data() {
        return {
            selected: '',
            flagValue: false
        }
    },
    methods: {
        onChange(value) {
            if (this.selected !== value) {
                this.flagValue = true;
            } else {
                this.flagValue = false;
            }
        }
    },
    watch: {
        'flagValue': function() {
            console.log('it changed');
            this.$emit('select', this.flagValue);
        }
    },
    created() {
        console.log(this.flagValue);
        this.flagValue = this.isShowingUpdate;
    }
}
</script>
```

Basically, when the option in the **select box** changes, the boolean flag should be updated. However, in my child I am getting **undefined** for **isShowingUpdate**. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't the relation that you said between the two components.

The component that you called `parent` is in reality the child... and the child is `parent`.

The parent component is always the one that calls the other, in your case:

```
//Parent component
<template>
 ...
  <msm-select :options="policies" :model="isShowingUpdate" /> << the child
 ...
</template>
```

You should change the props/events between the two components.

**Edit:**

You can edit the:

```
onChange(value) {
            if (this.selected !== value) {
                this.flagValue = true;
            } else {
                this.flagValue = false;
            }
        }
```

To a new one like the following:

On the children:

```
onChange(value) {
            if (this.selected !== value) {
                this.flagValue = true;
            } else {
                this.flagValue = false;
            }
            this.$emit('flagChanged', this.flagValue)
        }
```

On the parent use the `emit` event to capture and call some other method:

```
//HTML part:
    <msm-select :options="payments" :model="isShowingUpdate" v-on:flagChanged="actionFlagChanged" />

//JS part:
    methods: {
        actionFlagChanged () {
             //what you want
        }
    }
```

Can I give you some `tips`?

- It's not a (very) good name of a function the one called: `onChange`
  inside a onChange event... try something like: updateFlag (more
  semantic).
- I think that you can delete the watch part and do it in the onChange
  event
- Try to find a good documentation/tutorial (i.e the official documentation) to learn more about parent/child communication.

Remember to add the event-bus import:

```
import { EventBus } from './event-bus'
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @JP. Aulet. What you said above makes perfect sense and I've amended my code. However, I am still unable to pass the prop value from the parent to the child (getting **undefined**). Would it help if I post my updated code?

Comment: Yes, update the code in order to get better help for the community! But maybe first try to read a little about parent-children comunication between components (double data binding, props, events, etc.)